# How to get all graphql schema query, mutation, subscribe

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql, graphql-compose, graphql-compose-mongoose

I am using nodejs with graphql and graphql-compose
so i define scheme as

```
schemaComposer.Query.addFields({
  Me: MyResolvers,
  Info: MyInfoResolvers,
  Post: PostResolvers
})

schemaComposer.Mutation.addFields({
    Login: MyLoginResolvers,
    Register: RegisterResolvers
})

schemaComposer.Subscription.addFields({
    Subscribe: Mysubscribe
})
```

So any function to get all query, mutation and subscribe to list array
example i need print to

```
[
  { operator: "Me", name: "Query" }
  { operator: "Info", name: "Query" }
  { operator: "Post", name: "Query" }
  { operator: "Login", name: "Mutation" }
  { operator: "Register", name: "Mutation" }
  { operator: "Subscribe", name: "Subscription" }
]


or Object is best
{
   Query: ["Me", "Info", "Post"],
   Mutation: ["Login", "Register"],
   Subscription: ["Subscribe"]
}
```

I can parse the query from request using parse function from graphql library to get operator and name using

```
import { parse } from "graphql"



const query:any = parse(context.req.body?.query)
const operator = query.definitions[0]?.operation
const name = query.definitions[0]?.selectionSet?.selections[0]?.name?.value
```

Now i need list all defined query, mutation, subscribe in schema? is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try leaving introspection on. [[docs]](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/)

Comment: can you explain, any example ? @Dan

Comment: Most graphql servers come with a Graphiql interface for testing and building queries. These interfaces can autocomplete inputs because graph is strong typed. The way these interfaces get the data they need for autocomplete is by doing introspection queries the graph server auto-generates. I don't know much about them but they could be used if it's necessary. IDK what OP is trying to do tho..